# Force Messenger webview in browser not to open new tab

Tags: facebook, webview, messenger, facebook-chatbot

Is it possible to keep the user flow inside the messenger web view?

My user flow is:

- A button opens a web view
- User fills a few fields for authentication
- User is redirected for payment - **this opens in a new tab**
- The payment site redirects the user back to the original host

For some reason, browsers tend to clear the localStorage, which break my code at the final redirection (I save auth token to localStorage to access backend). I think my problems would be solved if Messenger browser wouldn't open a new tab.

On mobile devices everything works fine.

Comment: Hope you are aware that by [Messenger Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#messengerplatform) you are not allowed to redirect users from messenger to outside sites that "collect payment information" without applying for Facebook's permission first.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for pointing that out! Do you know where can I apply for this permission?

Comment: Link to the form to apply is right there where is says that ...

Comment: I really don't know which part of the text you're referring to...

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/919889051467941

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to run webviews within the messenger using Messenger Extensions (SDK). You have to whitelist the domains and return header options:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com/
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/
```

However, there are some unsupported features for Web, which are available for mobile Messenger only:

- webview_height_ratio
- webview_share_button
- Navigation back buttons
- Dialog title
- Closing the webview via URL redirect
- getUserID()
- Payments

As you mentioned a payment site, that might still be a problem. More insight about Messenger Extentions you can find here: [Facebook Messenger SDK Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions?locale=en_US%20%22Facebook%20Messenger%20SDK%20Docs) and in this article: [Webviews In Messenger.com](https://medium.com/@rajeshjnair/webviews-start-supporting-in-messenger-com-and-facebook-chat-tabs-dc5a40e6165b)

Comment: So I can't force it, if I have no control over the used websites? I can't set these header at the payment site.

Comment: Well that I really don't know. You could try to use your own server for the webview and then redirect or iframe on your page into the payment provider.